# como criar um método genérico

Tags: java, genéricos

Muitas vezes eu tenho que fazer um método para buscar numa tabela, por exemplo getByCPF. Gostaria de fazer um método genérico que eu passe o nome da coluna e o que eu busco.

```
getByColumn(String column, Param param){

}
```

algo assim.

Comment: você quer enviar a coluna fora da função é isso ?